# WORDPRESS: Redirect a user if they are logged in/not logged in, only if they are on a certain url

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried multiple ways and edits to my functions.php file, however, I can't figure out or find a way which has worked for me.

A **logged in user** should be redirected from /zum-shop/ to /shop/
and a **not logged in user** should be redirected from /zum-shop/ to
/mein-konto/

What must be changed in the code?

```
add_action('init','redirect_to_shop');

function redirect_to_shop() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/zum-shop/') !== false )) {
        
        wp_redirect('/shop/');
        exit;
    
} else { 
        
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/zum-shop/') !== false ) {

    wp_redirect('/mein-konto/');
    exit;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works, the problem was a caching plugin.

Comment: Great to know it was just a caching problem! Just be careful in your tests for the URL. You are actually testing if the string `/zum-shop/` is contained in the request URI. But it shouldn’t match if the user comes with `/something/zum-shop/else`. Better use something like `preg_match('~^/zum-shop($|/.*)~i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to check if it starts with `/zum-shop` or `/Zum-Shop/` or `/zum-Shop/Weiter`.